# Is there a way to achieve Photoshop-like multiply, difference, etc layer effects with Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am looking for a way to achieve Photoshop-like layer effects such as multiply and difference (and screen) for Canvas + JavaScript.

Also, is there a blur effect for Canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Assuming at least some familiarity with image processing here. If that's not the case, you may want to refine your question or ask another one with a narrower scope.*)

Those layer effects are not that hard to achieve. [Wikipedia has descriptions of how they work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) as well as a few pointers. For *multiply* for example you multiply the values per channel and per pixel and divide the result by 255.

As for blur, that's usually done with a simple [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). See for example, [Wikipedia again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). Basically what you do when convolving a signal is to look at the neighborhood of a single pixel with varying weights (for a Gaussian blur those weights form the shape of a normal distribution in 2D). A simply box blur could use the matrix

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

which would just blur each pixel with its directly surrounding ones. Perform this three times on the image and you get a good approximation of a Gaussian blur as well.